# Use Google analytics to alert on traffic spike source

Tags: reporting, alerts, google-analytics

I use Google Analytics today to notify me of big traffic spikes.  In my case, a big traffic spike is typically due to a link from a prominent website.

Google Analytics includes a new "Intelligence" feature to report on spikes.  Unfortunately, today it only reports that I had a spike, but doesn't report the referring site; instead it reports the geographic region of the traffic, e.g. "California."

This isn't a very useful dimension to report on, because geography is almost never the *cause* of the traffic spike; it's almost always due to a referring site.

Is there a way to configure Google Analytics Intelligence to report on the cause (the referring site) of traffic spikes?

Comment: Have you asked on the Google forums? Seems to me to be the obvious place to start.

Comment: Yup http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Analytics/thread?tid=6d15c64413a16535&hl=en No response so far

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use the following Alert Conditions:

> This applies to: Referral Path
> Condition: Does not match exactly
> Value: (not set)
>
> Alert me when: Visits
> Condition: % increases by more than
> Value: 25
> Compared to: Previous day

You could also change the 'applies to' condition to a regex to filter out any regular refers that fluctuate above the increase % you treat as a spike.

Comment: Best answer so far.  Looks like Google Analytics isn't really meant to do this, and I can't test the alert before the bounty runs out, soooo here you go.

Comment: Thanks :-) I think Analytics should do this... it's a great use-case for the Intelligence component. If the settings I posted don't work for you (I still believe they should), then it would be a reasonable feature request.

Answer (score 1):

I'd take the Google Analytics alert as an indicator you should take a look at your logs.  Something like webalizer or awstats will give you the detail you want.  Analytics is good, but it can't tell you everything your log files can.